# Querying for more than one document inside of view with Motor

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado, tornado-motor

The `Motor` tutorial in the [latest doc](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-motor-with-gen-coroutine) shows how to get more than one document via `tornado.gen.couroutine`:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def do_find():
    cursor = db.test_collection.find({'i': {'$lt': 5}})
    for document in (yield cursor.to_list(length=100)):
        print document
```

It then demonstrates the output synchronously:

`IOLoop.current().run_sync(do_find)`

How can I alter this function so that I can call it from within an async `handler` and get a list of documents back?

Comment: Your code looks right to me. Sort of. What's that ":" doing at the end of the line with "to_list"? That's a syntax error, so I assume you're not really showing us the code that runs. Additionally, can you please show the full traceback, not just the error message?

Comment: I had wrapped marked the `get_users` function in `@tornado.web.asynchronous`. Have edited the question and posted the answer in case it helps someone, but will take it down if it's in the doc and I just missed it. Thank you very much for looking at the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
class AdminHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  @tornado.gen.coroutine
  def get_users(self):
    cursor = self.mc.web_app.user.find()
    users = [user['email'] for user in (yield cursor.to_list(length=1000))]
    raise tornado.gen.Return(users)

  @tornado.gen.coroutine
  def get(self):
    self.xsrf_token
    users = yield self.get_users()
    self.render('main/index.html', users=users)
```

Comment: Cool. No need for "asynchronous" with "coroutine" since Tornado 3.1, just "@tornado.gen.coroutine" is enough: http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.asynchronous